# Create a google calendar event from natural text

Tags: email, calendar

I receive many emails that have some events in them which I currently have to enter manually into my Google calendar. It would be great if I can automate this process as much as possible using some sort of natural language processing (or a very long list of regex's).

I would like to know if there are any solutions out there, especially in Emacs, before I start writing my own.

If there are no ready solutions, do you have any advice you can give me to implement the solution?

For example, based on [this article](https://edeferia.blogspot.com/2015/03/from-natural-language-to-calendar.html), I was thinking using OpenNLP would be a good idea.